# Comprehensive textbook in surgery theory

Tags: reference-request, geometric-topology, surgery-theory

I am currently reading *Prasolov & Sossinski: Knots, Links, Braids and 3-Manifolds* but I have a hard time understanding some of the more intuitive argument on the chapters of surgery in 3 manifolds, even in the beggining chapters of heegard splittings, lens spaces e.t.c.

I was wondering if there exists a book or set of notes giving a more comprehensive introduction, meaning that I am looking for a text with more details and not assuming any prior familiriaty with the subject (however I have taken a first course in general and algebraic topology as well as a course on manifolds).

Comment: I don't have anything to recommend that directly matches what you ask for, but I suspect that you might be missing some basic material: besides general topology and algebraic topology, a course on differential topology is rather important. Once you have a solid background in differential topology, one of the best early exposures to surgery ideas is Milnor's book "Morse theory".

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you . Do you have any suggestion for Differential topology books? Is guillemin & pollack enough ?

Comment: Guilleman and Pollack is good. They present applications of transversality theory, which is a kind of "prerequisite" for surgery theory. Also good is Milnor's book "Topology from the differentiable viewpoint".

Comment: @LeeMosher How much algebraic topology is needed ? i'm planning to read Rolfsen and this book too (I already read half of Lee's smooth manifold. But i dont think thats enough).

Comment: Algebraic topologic is not at all important for understanding the basic definitions of surgery. However, the real point of surgery is its applications to algebraic topology, in particular its applications to homology groups. You'll see that from Milnor's "Morse Theory", for example. (And then, of course, the algebraic topology conclusions one obtains from surgery theory can then be applied back to reach a much deeper understanding of manifolds themselves.)